# How to implement GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory in Android application to create an OpenGL ES context so that we can check the OpenGL ES version?

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

My question is **How could I print the maximum `OpenGL ES version` supported by a physical device by implementing `GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory` ?**

I was following a tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/opengl/environment) on how to setup
the environment in an Android application using OpenGL ES.

The way I structure my code is exactly like the tutorial tells me.

1. My Main Activity is setup like this `class MainActivity: Activity()` whereby `Activity` is
   from `android.app.Activity` package.
2. Inside `MainActivity` there is an instance of `GLSurfaceView` from `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView` package.
3. A class named `MyGLSurfaceView` is created to implement or inherits from `GLSurfaceView`.
   Inside it, it has an instance of `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`.
4. A class named `MyGLRenderer` is created to implement or inherits from `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`.
5. A class named `Model` is created in the same package with the required `OpenGL ES` class to create the environment.

so, `Model` class needs to access Android `Context` from `android.content.Context` package to do some work, like to access a file.

In [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/opengl/about-opengl), it tells me to write:

```
private const val EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098
private const val glVersion = 3.0
private class ContextFactory : GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory {

override fun createContext(egl: EGL10, display: EGLDisplay, eglConfig: EGLConfig): 
EGLContext {

    Log.w(TAG, "creating OpenGL ES $glVersion context")
    return egl.eglCreateContext(
            display,
            eglConfig,
            EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
            intArrayOf(EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, glVersion.toInt(), EGL10.EGL_NONE)
    ) // returns null if 3.0 is not supported
    }
}
```

But, I still do not understand how to implement this code. Because, I already created `OpenGL ES` context inside the `constructor` of `MyGLSurfaceView` like so:

```
init {

    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2)

    renderer = MyGLRenderer(context)
    
    // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
    setRenderer(renderer)
    }
```

It says there, in the documentation that I must create the `OpenGL ES` context first before
reading the version that the device can support, like the maximum version it can run.

The problem is `GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory` is a `static interface` which means it is a
`global` or `shared` object and need to be implemented first, i.e inherits from that class and overriding the `createContext()` method and `destroyContext()`.

How should I implement `GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory`? should I declare it as nested class of `MyGLSurfaceView`.

I have tried like this by creating a nested class called `ContextFactory` which implements the interface `GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory`:

```
private const val EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION=0x3098
private const val glVersion=3.0
const val TAG="ContextFactory"
class MyGLSurfaceView(context: Context):GLSurfaceView(context) {
private val renderer: MyGLRenderer

init {

    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2)

    renderer = MyGLRenderer(context)
    //renderMode = GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY
    // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
    setRenderer(renderer)
    glGetString(glVersion.toInt())
    //I am assuming `ContextFactory` has already been instantiated since it implements
    //a `static interface` so, I do not need to create another instance of it here in 
    // the constructor. So, I just directly trying to read `maximum OpenGL ES version` 
    //supported in my device.
    }
```

but in the `logcat` inside `warn` category it says:

`Rcall to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)`
`Reading a NULL string not supported here.`

`MyGLSurfaceView` class looks like this:

```
 import android.content.Context
 import android.opengl.GLES20.glGetString
 import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
 import android.util.Log
 import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10
 import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig
 import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLContext
 import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLDisplay

 private const val EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION=0x3098
 private const val glVersion=3.0
 const val TAG="ContextFactory"
 class MyGLSurfaceView(context: Context):GLSurfaceView(context) {
     private val renderer: MyGLRenderer

    init {
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2)
        renderer = MyGLRenderer(context)
        setRenderer(renderer)
        glGetString(glVersion.toInt())
    }

    private class ContextFactory: GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory{
        override fun createContext(egl: EGL10?, display: EGLDisplay?, eglConfig: 
        EGLConfig?): EGLContext? {
            Log.w(TAG, "creating OpenGL ES $glVersion context")
            if (egl != null) {
                return egl.eglCreateContext(
                    display,
                    eglConfig,
                    EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
                    intArrayOf(EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, glVersion.toInt(), 
                    EGL10.EGL_NONE)
                )
            }
            return null
        }

        override fun destroyContext(p0: EGL10?, p1: EGLDisplay?, p2: EGLContext?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a class that inherits from `GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory` interface like so:

```
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
import android.util.Log
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10 //make sure to import from 
//javax not from `android.opengles.*` package
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLContext
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLDisplay


private const val EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098
private const val glVersion = 3.3

class ContextFactory : GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory {
    override fun createContext(egl: EGL10, display: EGLDisplay, eglConfig: 
        EGLConfig): EGLContext {
         // returns null if 3.0 is not supported
        Log.w("OpenGl version", "creating OpenGL ES $glVersion context")
        return egl.eglCreateContext(
            display,
            eglConfig,
            EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
            intArrayOf(EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, glVersion.toInt(), 
            EGL10.EGL_NONE)
        ) //
    }

    override fun destroyContext(egl: EGL10, display: EGLDisplay, context: 
        EGLContext) {
        egl.eglDestroyContext(display, context)
    }
}
```

in `MyGLSurfaceView` class:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView(context: Context) : GLSurfaceView(context) {
     private val renderer: MyGLRenderer
     private var previousX: Float = 0f
     private var previousY: Float = 0f

init {
    //setEGLContextClientVersion(2)
    setEGLContextFactory(ContextFactory()) //need to use this function 
    //instead of the above one
    renderer = MyGLRenderer(context)
    setRenderer(renderer)
}
```

if the program crashes, it means, it doesn't support the current version that was specified in the `ContextFactory` class. If it can run smoothly, it means it supports the currently specified version.

One more thing `GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory` is actually a normal interface, not a `static` or `global` interface when I thought previously.